# iOS - iphone/ipad versioning

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, project-management, versioning

I currently have an iphone app that I want to make an ipad version of. I don't want it to be "universal" though. I want to sell the ipad version for a different price than the iphone version.

My question - what is the best way to go about this in Xcode? Do I just copy the project and then maintain two separate projects, and do the ipad build from the new project? Seems this is the only way to go, but will be a pain to make updates to both. Suggestions? Advice? Thanks.

Comment: I would be cautious about taking this approach, since you may frustrate users who own both devices. I have both an iPhone and an iPad, and I would certainly think twice about paying more than double to use a single app on both.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I currently sell the iphone version for $.99, and I think the iPad version is worth at least $2.99. So it's either create a separate iPad version for $2.99, or charge $2.99 for a universal version, which means someone with an iphone or ipod only would have to pay the $2.99.

Comment: Or another option, which is what I do with one of my apps: have a universal version (maybe even released as universal later as a gift to your users) + an iPhone-only version. It's worked pretty well for my apps (+ don't underestimate the appeal of universal apps!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In almost the same way that you would make an app universal, you can make a separate iPad version. *Disclaimer: I haven't actually done this before, I went the universal route.* Now what you need to do is first right click on your target and click "Upgrade Current Target for iPad..." Then click "Two device-specific applications" and "OK." Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I went through something similar with my apps. I had a working iPhone version of an app that I wanted to port to the iPad. I created an iPad-specific project and added the share-able code to this. Fortunately for me, I had a pretty clean separation of the data and UI code and was able to share most of the data code; in the new iPad project, the only thing I had to write new code for was the UI stuff.

I'm totally open to changing the way I handle this separation. In theory, it would seem that you could specify different bundle identifiers and turn on/off settings to enable iPad or iPhone versions. But I had decided that it'd just be simpler to separate out my iPad/iPhone projects.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using two projects, add an iPad app target to your iPhone project. This way, whenever you change shared code, it is updated for both apps.